# jQuery Ajax function is fired multiple times? function call is kind of repetitive?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, function

weird thing I can't find a reason for. I have a simple function that is triggered if a `<a>` element has an attribute called `data-ajax-link`. The attribute contains a simple url.

So if a link has this attribute I call the following function I prevent Default and call my ajaxFunction …

```
function ajaxLoadJson(loadUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: loadUrl,
        dataType: "text json",
        success: function(jsonObject,status) {

            notificationBoxOutput(jsonObject.status, jsonObject.data);
            console.log("function() ajaxLoadJson : " + status);

        },
        error: function(requestObject,status) {
            notificationBoxOutput("warning", "request not successfull, please try again");
            console.log("function() ajaxLoadJson : " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

The `loadUrl` parameter is the url in the data-ajax-link attribute I'm handing over to the function.

So **MY PROBLEM**

Imagine I have multiple links with this `data-ajax-link` attribute on my page. Each link performs a deletion-command back on the server. This works actually works fine however the `ajaxLoadJson-Function` I posted above gets fired twice if delete objects, three times if I delete three objects.

So again, if I click one of those links for the first time my console prints `function() ajaxLoadJson : success`. If I then click another of those links suddenly my console prints `function() ajaxLoadJson : success` another two times. And so on.

Any idea why this happens. The function should of course be triggered only once if a link is clicked.

---

**Some more information**

On domready I call the function `interceptAjaxLinks()` which makes sure all links with the class a.ajaxLink are triggerd as ajax link. So actually above I gave you some wrong information. I'm not listening for links with the attribute "data-ajax-link" but rather apply the function to all links with a class of "ajaxLink". If triggered I simply use the `attr()` selector to get the data-ajax-link attribute and pass it on to the `ajaxLoadJson` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            interceptAjaxLinks();
});
```

---

```
function interceptAjaxLinks(targetBox) {

    console.log("function() interceptAjaxLinks : " + "start");

    if (targetBox == undefined) {
        targetBox = document;
    } else {
        targetBox = "div." + targetBox;
    }

    $(targetBox).find("a.ajaxLink").live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        ajaxLoadJson($(this).attr("data-ajax-link"));

    });

    console.log("function() interceptAjaxLinks : " + "end");
}
```

This function gets only triggered once just on domready.

---

**HTML**

My html structure looks like this.

```
<div class="nameListBox">

    <!-- name container start -->
    <div class="nameBox">

        <a href="/watch/72/a-new-name">
            <div class="infoBox">
                <div class="imageBox"></div>
                    <b>views:</b> 0
                    <b>comments:</b> 0
                </span>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div class="menuBox">
                <a href="/name/edit/72"><button class="button1">edit</button></a>
                <a href="/name/manage/72"><button class="button1">manage</button></a>
                <a href="#" class="ajaxLink deleteBtn" data-ajax-link="/ajax/name/delete/72"><button class="button1">delete</button></a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- name container start -->
    <div class="nameBox">

        <a href="/watch/68/a-new-name">
            <div class="infoBox">
                <div class="imageBox"></div>
                    <b>views:</b> 0
                    <b>comments:</b> 0
                </span>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div class="menuBox">
                <a href="/name/edit/68"><button class="button1">edit</button></a>
                <a href="/name/manage/68"><button class="button1">manage</button></a>
                <a href="#" class="ajaxLink deleteBtn" data-ajax-link="/ajax/name/delete/68"><button class="button1">delete</button></a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

So I have multiple nameBox'es inside of my `div.nameListBox`. Each of those nameBox'es has a little menu with a "edit", "manage" and "delete" button. Only the "delete" button is a ajaxLink.

Comment: Can you please show us your full js code?

Comment: check your selector that you uses to get the desired link it may be select other links too

Comment: updated my question with a little bit more information! @Nicola Peluchetti that's actually all that should matter.

Comment: You know you can use `.data('ajaxLink')` to get the `data-ajax-link` value?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to post more code, perhaps your HTML so we can see the structure of the DOM elements.

In my view the `targetBox` is probably binding to overlapping elements; possibly your container and the actual box itself.

My advice is to use the selector's id or class to precisely identify the element you want to invoke the code, not the `document` element.

Comment: I don't want to use the `deleteBtn` class to precisely identify the element because I have multiple other buttons on that page that should trigger the ajaxFunction. I don't want to repeat code and apply an event handler to each class. Maybe my html is just crappy and therefore this happens.

Comment: aha! no wonder you cannot select the element - you don't identify the `<div>` with a unique id: `<div id="box1">` . If you did this, then when you used Jquery, you could use the selector `$("#box1").click()` to identify the unique element. I pasted this to my answer but actually that's an answer in itself: "...use the selector's id..." I'd say it's good HTML practice to identify your elements with a unique ID attribute, and also your form elements with the `name` attribute.

Comment: however that's not what I want. I wanna use the same function for multiple buttons with the class .ajaxLink. Therefore I don't want to select by id. Shouldn't this actually work the way it is. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think you are trying to over-simplify to the point where you are removing the bare minimum. It seems you are trying to create a one size fits all function that can be triggered by anything and still end up with the "correct" result. I would argue that you need to be able to create a test condition *somewhere* in your code for it to work, but you are effectively ruling out the use of `deleteBtn` and class selectors and ids. How else do you propose to make the test for your conditions?

Comment: Let me explain it another way. You could have one function that is triggered onclick, but then says "if link is clicked do A, if any delete button is clicked do B, if every other button is clicked do C", but you are ruling out the ability to identify the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I see several possible reasons.

1) Multiple event binding (maybe you call something similar to binding somewhere else. I don' belive in it much. But still who knows. Try to call [die](http://api.jquery.com/die/) before calling live()

2)Try to add event bubbling [prevention](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). There could be some issues with clicking on the container. And also just in case check if "this" is actually the clicked < a > element and not something else here :

`ajaxLoadJson($(this).attr("data-ajax-link"));`

Comment: "this" is always the right a element. Thank you for the tip but that's not the case. `e.stopPropagation` doesn't do the trick. Where do I apply the die() method?

Comment: Probably right before calling live. To ensure there is no multiple binding. Try also to call die and live **evertyime** you delete item (or send request). Thats ugly but just for testing purpose..

Comment: you meen like ` $(targetBox).find("a.ajaxLink").die('click');` right? that doesn't change anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: Strange. I took all your code into test project.. Works good for me. Delete function is called once.  Does that code available somewhere public ? and BTW why do you store the link and not jsut an id everywhere  ?

Comment: What do you mean with "storing an id everywhere"?

Comment: Why not use  `<a href="#" class="ajaxLink deleteBtn" data-ajax-id="72"><button class="button1">delete</button></a>` or  `<a href="/ajax/name/delete/72" class="ajaxLink deleteBtn" ></a>`